# Measuring the accuracy of floating point results to N decimal places

Tags: python, decimal, floating

I'm testing some implementations of Pi in python (64-bit OS) and am interested in measuring how accurate the answer is (how many decimal places were correct?) for increasing iterations. I don't wish to compare more than 15 decimal places because beyond that the floating point representation itself is inaccurate.

E.g. for a low iteration count, the answer I got is

```
>>> x
3.140638056205993
```

I wish to compare to math.pi

```
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
```

For the above I wish my answer to be 3 (3rd decimal is wrong)
The way I've done it is:

```
>>> p = str('%.51f' % math.pi)
>>> q = str('%.51f' % x)
>>> for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(p,q)):
...     if a != b:
...         break
```

The above looks clumsy to me, i.e. converting floats to strings and then comparing character by character, is there a better way of doing this, say more Pythonic or that uses the raw float values themselves?

Btw I found math.frexp, can this be used to do this?

```
>>> math.frexp(x)
(0.7851595140514982, 2)
```

Comment: That's comparing within a specified delta / epsilon, I am not after that. E.g. the difference in the above two values is 0.0009545973838003263, which I can't translate to '3rd decimal place'

Comment: well if you are really interested in the decimal values, I'm not sure there's much better: a same difference of 0.02 can have an impact on the 2nd or 1st decimal depending on the case: 2.34 vs 2.36 or 2.39 vs 2.41.

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the logarithm of the difference between the two

```
>>> val = 3.140638056205993
>>> epsilon = abs(val - math.pi)
>>> abs(int(math.log(epsilon, 10))) + 1
3
```

Essentially, you're finding out which power of 10 does it take to equal the difference between the two numbers.  This only works if the difference between the two numbers is less than 1.

Comment: and might give an off by one result if OP is really after the first decimal that is different (see my comment)

Comment: Thanks Brendan, when I try it with different numbers it's not quite right...
>>> u = 3.14623
>>> o = 3.14622
>>> e = abs(o - u)
>>> abs(int(math.log(e, 10)))
4
I'd expect 5 since the 5th decimal is off. I guess your method is accurate within 1 decimal place?

Comment: @user1044615 I left out a `+1` in my answer, if you add that, it should give you the correct result. However it still will be off by one in cases like JulienBernu pointed out

Comment: For example `u = 3.14629  o=3.14630`.  Those numbers are off only by `.00001`, just like in the example you gave, but I think you would expect a `4`, not a `5` in that case

Comment: @JulienBernu yes, I'm after exact decimal places, so 2.41 vs 2.39 would have to be diff of 1st place. Ok, so looks like not a better way, thank you

Comment: Thanks @BrendanAbel